# How to get count of objects in database for a particular user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Right now my dashboard looks like this:

[image]

The white box should show the number of complaints that are registered by the user. But right now it shows the number of complaints registered by all users. What should I do to only get the count for a particular user?

views.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
   count = Complaint.objects.all().count()
   context = {'count':count}
   return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

template:

```
<p>{{count}}</p>
```

What should I do??

Comment: Can you add the `Complaint` model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) the QuerySet with the logged-in user as,

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    count = Complaint.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
    context = {'count': count}
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```